# Ways to align vertices on a bent cylinder

Tags: modeling

I have a cylinder that is bent into this shape

[image]

what are the ways in which the vertices can be aligned so that the cylinder would be straight again?

So far i've tried selecting each edge loop and then scaling them on an axis by 0 but it gets cumbersome if theres alot of edges

I have also tried switching to top down view and then snapping them to certain vertices so that it is aligned but this also becomes cumbersome with more vertices and edges

Whats a better way to do this?

Comment: if you bent this only on one axis you could try to select the centered one, enable proportional editing and the try to move it back by tweaking the radius and moving your mouse. But why can't you just add a new cylinder? or...if the cylinder might have modifiers and so on...delete all vertices in edit mode and add a new cylinder in edit mode?

Comment: If you don't need the intervening edge loops, you could box select all the vertices between the two end loops and delete them. Then select the top and bottom loops and use Edge > Bridge Edge Loops to reconnect them.